# How to remove TypeError: "x" is not a function?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to learn how to make a discord bot and pull data from this API called Ergast (http://ergast.com/mrd). I found this npm (https://github.com/estevE11/f1-stats) which uses NodeJS implementation to get a historical record of F1 data from Ergast API. Sorry for the bad wording I am still trying to learn the lingo.

I followed what was stated in the npm documentation for installing it and tried using the example to get data from the API. However when I run the code in index.js I get the error "TypeError: "x" is not a function". When I go into the node_modules "f1-stats" folder and run the code from main.js I do get the correct result.

index.js:

```
const client = new Discord.Client(); //This will be our client 
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');//const PREFIX = '!';
const f1s = require('f1-stats');

//module.exports.f1s = f1s; //Still causes the TypeError

f1s("2008 drivers", (res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

The error message I get in index.js:

```
f1s("2008 drivers", (res) => {
^

TypeError: f1s is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RyanPC\Documents\DiscordBot\index.js:8:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
```

node_modules/f1-stats/main.js:

```
const f1s = require("./f1-stats"); // "./" is used because module is located in the same folder as the Node.js file

f1s("2008 drivers", (res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

when I run it in node_modules/f1-stats/main.js:

```
{ MRData:
   { xmlns: 'http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4',
     series: 'f1',
     url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2008/drivers.json',
     limit: '30',
     offset: '0',
     total: '22',
     DriverTable: { season: '2008', Drivers: [Array] } } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `f1-stats` doesn't export anything so when you import it. It is empty. The correct file you need to import is `f1-stats/f1-stats`.

```
const f1s = require('f1-stats/f1-stats');
```

Answer (score 0):

try importing f1s properly , you are getting error because you have not imported the function properly , in other words...check what is being exported from what are you trying to import....hope it solves the problem.